# Calculate equidistant point with minimal distance from 3 points in N-dimensional space

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I'm trying to code the [Ritter's bounding sphere algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere#Ritter.27s_bounding_sphere) in arbitrary dimensions, and I'm stuck on the part of creating a sphere which would have 3 given points on it's edge, or in other words, a sphere which would be defined by 3 points in N-dimensional space.

That sphere's center would be the minimal-distance equidistant point from the (defining) 3 points.

I know how to solve it in 2-D (circumcenter of a triangle defined by 3 points), and I've seen some vector calculations for 3D, but I don't know what the best method would be for N-D, and if it's even possible.

(I'd also appreciate any other advice about the smallest bounding sphere calculations in ND, in case I'm going in the wrong direction.)

Comment: This seems more like a mathematical problem more then a coding/programming issue. This might be better in [Mathermatica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The link does not mention a sphere given by three points, but a sphere containing a sphere and a point external to the latter. The center of the new sphere is along the line from the old center and the external point, midpoint of the point and the antipodal point on the sphere.

Comment: The title of the question is not the same as the content. I think you need to find an equidistant point that also minimises the distance.  Try to edit the question to say more clearly what you really are trying to do.

Comment: @george You're right. Sorry.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do you have any proof that that would be the minimal bounding sphere center?

Comment: As explained in the link, Ritter's method does not compute a  minimal bounding sphere.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So do you think that's how it's supposed to be done?
I thought the imperfection was due to the method of choosing the points and not within the process of making a sphere from chosen points.

Comment: added answer I recommend to use the second solution it is much simpler to code ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so if I get it right:

Wanted point `p` is intersection between 3 hyper-spheres of the same radius `r` where the centers of hyper-spheres are your points `p0,p1,p2` and radius `r` is minimum of all possible solutions. In **n-D** is arbitrary point defined as `(x1,x2,x3,...xn)`

**so solve following equations:**

```
|p-p0|=r
|p-p1|=r
|p-p2|=r
```

where `p,r` are unknowns and `p0,p1,p2` are knowns. This lead to `3*n` equations and `n+1` unknowns. So get all the nonzero `r` solutions and select the minimal. To compute correctly chose some non trivial equation `(0=r)` from each sphere to form system of `n+1`  =equations and `n+1` unknowns and solve it.

**[notes]**

To ease up the processing you can have your equations in this form:

```
(p.xi-p0.xi)^2=r^2
```

and use `sqrt(r^2)` only after solution is found (ignoring negative radius).

**there is also another simpler approach possible:**

You can compute the plane in which  the points `p0,p1,p2` lies so just find `u,v` coordinates of these points inside this plane. Then solve your problem in **2D** on `(u,v)` coordinates and after that convert found solution form `(u,v)` back to your `n-D` space.

[image: plane u,v coordinates]

```
n=(p1-p0)x(p2-p0); // x is cross product
u=(p1-p0); u/=|u|;
v=u x n; v/=|v|; // x is cross product
```

if memory of mine serves me well then conversion `n-D -> u,v` is done like this:

```
P0=(0,0);
P1=(|p1-p0|,0);
P2=(dot(p2-p0,u),dot(p2-p0,v));
```

where `P0,P1,P2` are **2D** points in `(u,v)` coordinate system of the plane corresponding to points `p0,p1,p2` in `n-D` space.

conversion back is done like this:

```
p=(P.u*u)+(P.v*v);
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. This helps a lot! I'll try to implement it!

Answer (score 1):

My Bounding Sphere algorithm only calculates a near-optimal sphere, in 3 dimensions.

Fischer has an exact, minimal bounding hyper-sphere (N dimensions.) See his paper: http://people.inf.ethz.ch/gaertner/texts/own_work/seb.pdf.

His (C++/Java)code: https://github.com/hbf/miniball.

Jack Ritter
jack@houseofwords.com